# How to measure image distortion?

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics

Threre are two images: original and compressed (or saved without compression) using some lossy algorithm.Is there a correct way to measure distortion without knowing what compression algorithm was used?
I don't need SIFT or something like that, because there are no rotation, scale or other transformation, just compression artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have both images, you can compute MSE (mean squared error) very easily.  Pseudo-code:

```
square_error = 0;
foreach pixel
{
    error = original[pixel] - compressed[pixel];
    square_error = square_error + error*error;
}
mean_square_error = square_error / number_of_pixels;
```

Another metric is PSNR, which is a scaled form of MSE.  Read more [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/psnr.html) and [here.](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/VELDHUIZEN/node18.html)

Comment: That methods are suitable enough, but is there a method to compare images in "more human-like" way?
For example, if to clean every odd row and column of a photo, it remains well recognizable for me, but PSNR shows rather poor value.

Comment: That sounds like a rather subjective measure, rather than an objective measure.  There was some work on that with "just noticeable difference" measures, but those are at the other end of the range (ie. at the threshold where "lossy" started to lose "just enough" information to be noticeable).  A quick Google search for more general measures turns up papers like this one: http://stefan.winklerbros.net/Publications/icip1998.pdf  You might Google on "image distortion metrics" for more options.